# I am trying to forecast data using Exponential smoothing in Python . However after fitting the model, Forecast() is not accepting steps as argument

Tags: python, forecasting

This the code I am using to forecast my data using Exponential Smoothing:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing
model = ExponentialSmoothing(traindata)
ets_fit = model.fit(smoothing_level = 0.2,optimized = False )
train['fittedvalues'] = ets_fit.fittedvalues
ets_pred = ets_fit.forecast(len(test))
```

I am getting the following error as :
TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting `n`, use `n * obj.freq`

How can I mention the number of steps/number of future forecasts required here?

Comment: Have you tried multiplying the length of the test data by your time between observations? Seems like that's what the error is asking you to do.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying to forecast weekly data and anything I try multiplying , it is throwing an error. As per forecast(), we need to specify 'steps' as arg. Should we now use anything regarding the frequency of the data.